# Lambda if else statements returning True when argument equal to 1

Tags: python, search, lambda, boolean, reduce

I am struggling to debug my code and I think the issue I am facing is  that when 1 is in the argument, it returns as True regardless of whether it is the correct key. Is there a way to stop this from happening?

```
def reduce_search(L, x): #L is a list, and x is the key to find in the list
    #FIX
    return reduce(lambda y,z: True if (y == True or z == True) else (True if (y == x or z == x) else False), False, L) #NOTE: not using the imported reduce method

def test_reduce_search():
    assert reduce_search([1, 3, 5, 4, 2, 9, 7], 2) == (2 in [1, 3, 5, 4, 2, 9, 7]) #return true
    assert reduce_search([1, 3, 5, 2, 9, 7], 99) == (99 in [1, 3, 5, 4, 2, 9, 7]) #return false
```

Comment: What do you mean 'not using the imported reduce method'? Which reduce are you using? Where is it from?

Answer (score 2):

It's because `1 == True`.

I think you just want:

```
from functools import reduce
def reduce_search(L, x):
    return reduce(lambda acc, item: item == x or acc, L, False)
```